# How to construct a partial set of inputs using Singular in lombok

Tags: java, lombok

If I receive Foo foo1, Foo foo2 as inputs, how do I use builder to construct a Bar.

```
createBar(Foo foo) {
  Bar bar = Bar.builder.foo(foo).build();
}
```

How do I support this in a generic fashion, would it be preferable to construct a List and set all the Foo(s), if a dynamic set of Foo(s) could be passed to the createBar method

```
createBar(Foo foo1, Foo foo2 ...)
```

Class definition

```
@Builder
class Bar {

  @Singular
  private List<Foo> foos;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not as fluent as you might hope, but it's quite compact, I think:

```
createBar(Baz baz, Foo... foos) {
  BarBuilder builder = Bar.builder();
  Arrays.stream(foos).forEach(builder::foo);
  Bar bar = builder.baz(baz)
                   .build();
}
```

Comment: If the createBar method has other attributes in the method parameters, I am assuming this would not work and I have to pass a List as an argument. Kindly confirm

Comment: It will work if the varargs argument is the last one.

Comment: I have more than few such objects, so this solution would be complicated to implement